# Сортировка элементов jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Всем привет. Такая проблемка: Есть  такой пример с сайта jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/ui/jqueryui.custom.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" href="/ui/jqueryui.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
        ul {list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0; margin-bottom:10px;}
        li {margin:5px; padding:5px; width:150px;}
        #sortable{float:left; border:1px solid #eee; position:absolute; top:70px; left:160px}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

      <ul>
        <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Перенеси в группу</li>
      </ul>
      <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">Элемент 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Элемент 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Элемент 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Элемент 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default">Элемент 5</li>
      </ul>

      <script>
        $("#sortable").sortable({ revert:true });
        $("#draggable").draggable({
          connectToSortable:"#sortable",
          helper: "clone",
          revert:"invalid"
        });

        // отменим возможность выделять текст внутри элементов
        $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Помогите плиз, сделать так, чтобы список из этого примера отображался горизонтально и функциональность сохранилась, но не вертикально, а горизонтально.
Спасибо =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для тега `li` добавьте свойство `float` со значение `left`.

Результат смотри **[тут](http://jsfiddle.net/TaBz5/)**.